# SQLITE Database not updating the TABLE

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite

***TABLE NOT UPDATING*****HOW TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

```
public String getElapsedTime(String session_id, String time) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    Log.d("CHINMAY", "Update in Sql get ElapsedTime " + session_id + "\n" + time);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ELAPSED_TIME, time);
    db.update(TABLE_SESSION_TEST, cv, "session_id=?", new String[]{session_id});
    db.endTransaction();
    return "Checking Update";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your transaction as "clean" by calling `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` before calling `db.endTransaction()`. If you do not set your transaction as successful, your changes are immediately rolled back as soon as the transaction is ended (as it assumes there was an error).

For more information, see the [SQLiteDatabase documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setTransactionSuccessful())

Comment: I didn't understand how to clean.

Comment: db.update(TABLE_SESSION_TEST, cv, "session_id=?", new String[]{session_id}); db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

Comment: db.update() returns an integer of how many rows have been updated. When that code runs, does db.update() return a 0 or a 1? If it's a 0, check your data and query to make sure it's correct.

Comment: i changed the code and return boolean value output is coming  toast.message as true.But database i checked is not displaying.

Comment: Actually i tried the code is updated after some time. But when i move to next activity the value is not coming immediately

Comment: How can i make the sqlite database faster